# I can't figure this out, my script has an issue

Tags: javascript

[my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUVks.png)

```
   window.onkeydown = function(e) {
     var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
     if (code === 71) {
       alert("hi");
     }
   };



   window.onkeyup = function(e) {
     var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
     if (code === 69) {
       alert("hi");
     }
   };
```

dont mind the following text!! I thought this would be answered somewhere on SO, but I can't find it.

If I'm listening for a keypress event, should I be using .keyCode or .which to determine if the enter key was pressed?

I've always done something like the following:dont mind this text!!

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Why in the world did you create an image with your question's text instead of just typing it?

Comment: What is the issue? "dont mind this text!!" huh?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

something like this..

```
window.onload = function(e) {

  window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
      console.log('keydown: ' + e.keyCode);
      if (e.keyCode == 71) {
        alert("hi");
      }
  });


  window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
      console.log('keyup: ' + e.keyCode);
      if (e.keyCode == 69) {
         alert("hi");
      }
  });

}
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for thx a lot.

Comment: *"something like this.."* doesn't really mean anything. Are you saying that the OP should use `keyCode` and not `which`? If yes, why? If you don't elaborate, no one can learn anything.